# Insert Formula into cell and extend down

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to insert some formulas to the following cells, but I always get a runtime error. What do I need to change on my code?

```
"F3" =IF(ROW()>Config!$E$4,"",VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP((ROW(F3)-2)/Config!$E$2,0),Config!$G:$H,2,FALSE))

"G3" =IF(ROW()>Config!$E$4,"",VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP((ROW(F3)-2)/Config!$E$2,0),Config!$G:$H,2,FALSE))

"Q3" =IF(ROW()>Config!$E$4,"",IF(INDIRECT("Config!B"&ROW(Config!B2))=0,INDIRECT("Q"&(ROWS(Config!$B$2:B2)-(Config!$E$2-2))),Config!B2))

"R3" =IF(ROW()>Config!$E$4,"",IF(HLOOKUP(Q3,Report!$2:$65536,ROUNDUP(((ROW(R3)-2)/Config!$E$2),0)+1,FALSE)="Passed","OK","KO"))
```

I tried to use `Sheets("xy").Range("F1").Formula = "......"` and `Range("F3:F10").FillDown`, but without of luck.

Can you please help? I need to add these formulas to the appropriate cells and after that I need to pull down them to a given row number.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using too please.

Comment: When you try placing a formula (using VBA), you should not just take the formula as you write it directly in a cell. Usually, the problems appear in case of double quotes, which must be doubled. The above comment is relevant. Please, show us the code you used.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Something like `Range("F3").Formula = "=IF(ROW()>Config!$E$4,"""",VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP((ROW(F3)-2)/Config!$E$2,0),Config!$G:$H,2,FALSE))"` should work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Option Explicit

'INSERT FORMULA IN CELLS
Sub insert_formula()

'DECLARE VARIABLE
Dim ws As Worksheet

'SET WORKSHEET
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Config")

'NOTES: BASIC INSERT FORMULA
'Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Formula = "...."
'IF YOU FIND "" -> NEED CREATE DOUBLE KEY AS """"

'INSERT EACH CELLS
ws.Range("F3").Formula = "=IF(ROW()>Config!$E$4,"""",VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP((ROW(F3)-2)/Config!$E$2,0),Config!$G:$H,2,FALSE))"

ws.Range("G3").Formula = "=IF(ROW()>Config!$E$4,"""",VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP((ROW(F3)-2)/Config!$E$2,0),Config!$G:$H,2,FALSE))"

ws.Range("Q3").Formula = "=IF(ROW()>Config!$E$4,"""",IF(INDIRECT(""Config!B""&ROW(Config!B2))=0,INDIRECT(""Q""&(ROWS(Config!$B$2:B2)-(Config!$E$2-2))),Config!B2))"

ws.Range("R3").Formula = "=IF(ROW()>Config!$E$4,"""",IF(HLOOKUP(Q3,Report!$2:$65536,ROUNDUP(((ROW(R3)-2)/Config!$E$2),0)+1,FALSE)=""Passed"",""OK"",""KO""))"

End Sub
```

you can use filldown or use copy paste special formula here sample:

```
Option Explicit

'INSERT FORMULA IN CELLS (FILLDOWN OR COPY PASTE SPECIAL)
Sub insert_formula()

'DECLARE VARIABLE
Dim ws As Worksheet

'SET WORKSHEET
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Config")

'BASIC INSERT FORMULA
'Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Formula = "...."

'INSERT EACH CELLS
ws.Range("F3").Formula = "=IF(ROW()>Config!$E$4,"""",VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP((ROW(F3)-2)/Config!$E$2,0),Config!$G:$H,2,FALSE))"

'FILL FORMULA BASE ON SPECIFIC RANGE
'1. YOU CAN USE PASTE AS FORMULA
ws.Range("F3").Copy
ws.Range("F3:F10").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

'OR
'2. YOUCAN USE FILL DOWNN
ws.Range("F3:F10").FillDown

End Sub
```