# Using Macro to drag down formula if Cell E3 not Blank

Tags: excel, vba

I am beginner at VBA and want to know how to drag down formulas in cells F2:J2 down to F3:J3 if E3 is not blank.
And this updated each time **C5** value changed (It is drop down cell)

This is how my table format

[image]

Comment: See this as a start, looking in here helps before you post. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72434383/4961700

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I found a Solution for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this.
this Macro would hide/unhide rows from 5 to 15 if cell in col 6 have value (all row would be hidden if G5 is blank then G6 until G15)

```
Sub HideRowCellTextValue()
    StartRow = 5
    LastRow = 15
    iCol = 6
    For i = StartRow To LastRow
        If Cells(i, iCol).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
        Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

And I call this Macro each time value in cell K3 is change using this :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$K$3" Then
        Call HideRowCellTextValue
    End If
End Sub
```

Wish you all the best